# From where we can get how much storage we have consumed for OneDrive similar to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, onedrive

If we go to SharePoint admin center inside Office 365 we get this info on how many storage we have consumed from the total storage available to us:-

[image]

So how we can get similar info about one drive sites?

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive for Business runs on the SharePoint platform and is included in these totals. The total number you see there is the total storage for your organisation's subscription.

for more info see

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-collection-storage-limits

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click the OneDrive for work or school icon OneDrive notification tray icon/button in the Windows notification area, and then select Manage storage.
   [image]
2. If you want to see how much space you’re using, select View OneDrive for work or school storage.
   This opens a Storage Metrics page that shows you the size of each item you’re storing, and the percentage of available storage it’s using.
   [image]

Comment: Is there any update on this thread? Comment here if you still need any help.